# Showing an error when I tried to echo out an image inside a string

Tags: php, html, schema

I am getting an unexpected T string parse error, I don't know how to incorporate php into this itemprop, can anyone help

```
$str_policy_details .= '<img itemprop="image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($broker_details->BrokerImage); ?>"/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `<?php` when you are already inside PHP, which causes the issue. Please change your code to:

```
$str_policy_details .= '<img itemprop="image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($broker_details->BrokerImage) . '"/>';
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^-------------------------------------------^^^^
```